# How can I use a Scala class as the shared root object across class loaders?

Tags: java, scala, classloader

I have implemented a custom class loader in Scala that serves to isolate plugins from the main application.  At present I require a Java interface to act as the shared root object so my main application can use the plugin code.

Interface acting as shared root (I would like this to be Scala):

```
public interface Handler {
    public List<HandlerInfo> getHandlers();
}
```

Example plugin:

```
class MyPlugin extends Handler {
  def getHandlers: java.util.List[HandlerInfo] = // get some handlers
}
```

Usage in application:

```
val jarFile     = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/plugins/" + jarName)
val cl          = new PluginLoader(jarFile, this.getClass.getClassLoader) // my custom classloader
val classToLoad = Class.forName(className, true, cl)
val handler     = classToLoad.newInstance.asInstanceOf[Handler]
val handlers    = handler.getHandlers
```

This works fine, but my problem is that I have to keep this one Java class around (and the resulting build configuration).  I would like instead to use a Scala trait or abstract class, like this:

```
trait Handler {
  def getHandlers : List[HandlerInfo]
}
```

Then my plugin could look like this:

```
class MyPlugin extends Handler {
  def getHandlers: List[HandlerInfo] = // no more java.util.List
}
```

But I can't do this, because this line

```
val handler     = classToLoad.newInstance.asInstanceOf[Handler]
```

throws a `ClassCastException`, presumably because the Scala compiler doesn't generate a nice clean Java interface.  Is there any way around this, so I can have a Scala-only project?

Comment: Have you tried `def getHandlers: java.util.List`?  The Java interface wants the Java list, not the Scala one.

Comment: You want Handler.getHandlers to return java.util.List[HandlerInfo] -- just List will give you scala.collections.immutable.List by default.  If your trait has default implementations, you'll want to write delegates in the java implementation that delegate to Handler$class.  See twitter.github.com/scala_school/java.html for details (search for "Traits")

Comment: @RexKerr I don't want to use `java.util.List`.  I am only using it because I need the Java interface rather than a Scala trait/abstract class.  As I mentioned, the current implementation does work correctly.

Comment: Ok, perhaps my question is unclear.  I want to eliminate the Java version of the `Handler` interface.  I want a Scala version instead.  I am aware of the differences between `java.util.List` and `scala.collection.immutable.List`.

Comment: It might be clearer if you expanded on "this doesn't work".  What are you expecting and what are you getting instead?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what goes wrong.  "This doesn't work" is pretty uninformative.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not where you think it is; it's somewhere in your class loader.  The default class loader works just fine, even the Java one.  Evidence:

```
// File Handler.scala
trait Handler { def getHandlers: List[String] }

// File MyPlugin.scala
class MyPlugin extends Handler { def getHandlers = List("salmon", "cod") }

// File Interop.java
public class Interop {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Class classToLoad = Class.forName("MyPlugin");
      Handler handler = (Handler)classToLoad.newInstance();
      System.out.println("Class loader = "+handler.getClass().getClassLoader());
      System.out.println(handler.getHandlers());
    }
    catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Uh-oh: "+e); }
  }
}
```

And here we run it:

```
$ java -cp .:/usr/share/scala/2.10/lib/scala-library.jar Interop
Class loader = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1f3e8d89
List(salmon, cod)
$
```

with the Scala `List` and everything, and the new class loaded by the default Java class loader.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but what I don't understand is why the Java interface works fine while the Scala trait does not.  Using the interface, my custom loader behaves exactly as desired, so I guess I'm trying to understand what the difference is.

Comment: @rs_atl - Very hard to guess without knowing what your classloader does.  Why don't you reflect into your loaded class and look at the set of interfaces, etc..  There are plenty of ways to screw up class loaders.